# Huge number of io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache$Entry instances when grpc server started

Tags: java, memory-leaks, netty, heap-memory, grpc

We are running `grpc-java` version 0.8.0 server to handle remote calls. The server logic is quite simple, which is just fetching data specified by the given ids from DB and setting them into `redis` cache.

JVM arguments is configured as `-Xss256k -Xmx8G`. The JVM took 4GB (RES in `top`) memory as soon as the server was started and handling about 400 QPS. I issued jmap command `jmap -histo:live <pid>` and got the following dump file:

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name 
----------------------------------------------
   1:       4998400      119961600  io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache$Entry
   2:        212415       23503536  [B
   3:         11076       20170816  [Lio.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache$Entry;
   4:         70853       10010904  [C
   5:         28819        2518640  [Lio.netty.util.Recycler$DefaultHandle;
   6:         31232        1998848  com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$BooleanConnectionProperty
   7:          7287        1764136  [I
   8:         70000        1680000  java.lang.String
   9:         45766        1464512  java.util.Hashtable$Entry
  10:           134        1291992  [D
  11:         14376        1265088  io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf
  12:          5527        1160200  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;
  13:         16340        1116584  [[B
```

from which we could see that there were huge number of `io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache$Entry` instances which took about 100MB memory. (Note that `grpc` is using `netty` as its communication layer.) This seems to be abnormal. Even then, the in-heap Objects could not occupy as much as 4GB memory. This must due to the out-of-heap memory usages such as direct buffer used by `netty`.

Was there a out-of-heap memory leak?

Why could this happen? And how to solve or diagnose this issue?

Comment: Which version of grpc-java are you using? The number of PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf looks reasonable. I wonder if it is a problem with the PoolThreadCache. How many cores is the machine? When you say "4G memory," how are you measuring that?

Comment: @EricAnderson I'm using grpc 0.8.0, 4GB memory consumption is observed in `top`, the `RES` field.

Comment: Hmm... Could you try with Netty 4.1 Beta6 (group io.netty, artifact netty-codec-http2, version 4.1.0.Beta6). 0.8.0 used Beta 5, and Beta 6 includes an optimization that improves gRPC. I think it may improve your situation: https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/81fee66c78b6afad1d92647669c67bcf44f7cbdf

Comment: @EricAnderson I've upgraded to grpc 0.9.0 with netty 4.1 beta6 and got a significant improvement. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to grpc-java 0.9.0 or later (which brings in Netty 4.1 Beta6 or later) resolves the issue. It is unclear whether the problem was a bug or just inefficiency due to releasing buffers on a different thread than where they were allocated.